# The problem is the contract methods are working in class based components but not in functional based components. In next or react js both .why?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js

//This one is not working .it gives and error that module.methods.getdeployedContracts().call() is //not a function/

```
import factory from "../ethereum/factory";
import { Component } from "react";

function Home({ campaigns }) {
  console.log(campaigns);
  return <div>{campaigns[0]}</div>;
}
Home.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const res = await factory.methods.getDeployedContracts().call();
  return { campaigns: res };
};

export default Home;
```

// But when i change it to a class based componet it works //

```
import factory from "../ethereum/factory";
import { Component } from "react";

class Home extends Component {
  static async getInitialProps() {
    const campaigns = await factory.methods.getDeployedCampaigns().call();

    return { campaigns };
  }

  render() {
    const { campaigns } = this.props;
    console.log("campaigns", campaigns);
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{this.props.campaigns[0]}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKbYO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Check your functional component code.

```
function Home({ campaigns }) {
  console.log(campaigns);
  return <div>campaigns</div>; ---- Here is the problem
}
Home.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const res = await factory.methods.getDeployedContracts().call();
  return { campaigns: res };
};
```

You are just using campaigns as a text and rendering inside the div but you want to use that as a variable. Just do like how you are using it in the class component.

```
return <div>{campaigns}</div>;
```

That'll print whatever the value stored in the campaigns. If it's an array, iterate it and print its elements.

Comment: I am not intentionally doing that as text but the console.log is also giving error.

Comment: What's the error you are getting while doing `console.log` for campaigns?

Comment: Added an image with it . pls have a look

Comment: Can you tell me how are you exporting methods from your factory?
Based on the image I can tell you that the issue is related to imports. Just wanna make sure you used correct way of importing `default` or `named` imports that you used in the code

Comment: import web3 from "./web3";
import CampaignFactory from "./build/CampaignFactory.json";

console.log(CampaignFactory);
var instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
  CampaignFactory.abi,
  "0xB0f37952bd6E0AF905DFbD63df5AE1248D835695"
);

export default instance;
//this is the factory.js file